# Adding different product names for different websites programmatically

Tags: php, magento, store, product

I have two websites for specific Store Views - English & German. Normally, I could have maintained 1 website with two different Store Views, but it was the specific requirement of my client, to have each website for each specific store view.

Problem is I am not able to update / create different product names / descriptions, each for a product website, programmatically. I'm using this code to do it, which I found to be the same for different price:

```
$combinationWebsiteWithName = array('1' => 'product name 1', '2' => 'product name 2');

foreach ($combinationWebsiteWithName as $_eachWebsiteId => $_eachProductName) {
    $objWebsite = Mage::getModel('core/website')->load($_eachWebsiteId);
    $storeIds = $objWebsite->getStoreIds();
    $objProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                  ->setStoreId(end($storeIds))
                  ->load($productId);
    $objProduct->setName($_eachProductName);
    $objProduct->save();
}
```

Are there any errors in the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I found out what was wrong in there, and so here is the answer:-

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));

foreach ($websiteWiseProductNameArray as $_eachWebsiteId => $_eachProductName) {
    $objWebsite = Mage::getModel('core/website')->load($_eachWebsiteId);
    $storeIds = $objWebsite->getStoreIds();

    foreach ($storeIds as $_eachStoreId) {
        $objProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                            ->setStoreId($_eachStoreId)
                            ->load($productId);
        $objProduct->setData($targetAttrCode, $_eachProductName);
        $objProduct->save();

        unset($objProduct);
    }

    unset($storeIds, $objWebsite);
}
```

Last unexpected area of modification for me was setting the store ID to be that of Admin area, by using the following code: "`Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));`"